# Fourier transform of the realization of a stationary process in the space of tempered distributions?

Tags: probability-theory, fourier-analysis, time-series

A path of a stationary sequence of random variables $y_t$ does not have a discrete-time Fourier transform in the classical sense because it is not summable. This leads to considering the spectral representation theorem for stationary processes (a classical reference is Priestley's *Spectral Analysis and Time Series*).

However I believe such a path does admit a Fourier transform when seen as a tempered distribution $\sum_{- \infty}^\infty y_t \delta_t$ . What happens if you take this Fourier transform pointwise in $\omega$ ($\Omega$ the background probability space)?

- Does this create a random variable in the space of tempered distributions?
- Can you relate this candidate "random tempered distribution" to the spectral representation theorem or the power spectral density?

(I don't think discrete versus continuous time matters for my question.)